# embed icepdf into jpanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, icepdf

I'm working on a java application that can display pdf using Icepdf, suppose I've made the application layout as follows. and I want to paste pdfviewer icepdf on JPanel that has been provided.

[image: layout image i made with gui generator in netbeans]

I've been looking and trying to attach icepdf by adding a component that has been made in pallate manager

but for newbie like me i really have no clue to make the component. icepdf with the api provided by icepdf

i was trying to code like this.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package pdfreader;

//import static java.awt.SystemColor.window;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
public class PDFViewer {

String filePath = "C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PDFReader\\src\\pdfreader\\contoh.pdf";

// build a controller
SwingController controller = new SwingController();
SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);
controller.openDocument(filePath);   
}
```

whats make me confuse to is the 'controlller' give error but i thought it have been declarated before

error :

> package controller doesnt exist

i just want embeded the pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on this one but in Java you'll need move the "controller.openDocument(filePath); " into a constructor or method, or make the whole block static.